# Jquery 'onchange'' not behaving properly on ubuntu chrome whereas it works on all other browser and on all OS

Tags: jquery, select, click, onchange

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'select', function(e){

    var form = jQuery(this).form();
    var select_elt = jQuery(this);
    var option_elt  = jQuery(select_elt).find('option');
    $(option_elt).on('change', function (e) {
        form.trigger('submit', e);
    });
    });
```

Here is the code. The change condition on option_elt works alternatively (form trigger alternatively on option selection) on chrome browser on ubuntu whereas it works fine on all other browsers of all  OS.

******NOTE*****:  As soon as the page is loaded, select element updates dynamically hence change event is triggered then and there only which further call the ajax which again updates the select element in dom hence this way it becomes chain request which goes into infinite loop

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Based on your comments to [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43649733/1575353) it appears there are more details than described in the original post (e.g. with the change event of AJAX requests). Please **edit** your post to contain all of the details about that. Also it would help if you included the HTML of the form, select list, options, etc. Please read about [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Description updated

Answer (score 0):

Try the event delegation method.

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#idofselect",function (e) {
   //access your options
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the change event over a option you need to bind the event to the select

```
jQuery('body').on('change', 'select', function(e){
    var form = jQuery(this).closest('form');
        form.trigger('submit');
    });
```

for the flag you create a variable

```
var isAjax = false;

$.ajax({..,succcess(data){
  isAjax = true;
 //do things here that will trigger the change event
}})
//in the change event we test if the event is triggered by the user or by the ajax
 jQuery('body').on('change', 'select', function(e){
        if(!isAjax) {
        var form = jQuery(this).closest('form');
            form.trigger('submit');
         } else {isAjax = false;// the ajax completed the change event so we need to tell it to accept user change events}
        });
```

Comment: I cant use change on select as it Goes into infinite loop as form.trigger call an ajax which in response updates the select field, hence cant use change event here –

Comment: then that is your problem

Comment: you need to differentiate between the change event of the ajax call and the user change event

Comment: Ok thanks Man. Can you please tell how we can differentiate with flag ?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. But still the problem persist because ajax runs as soon as the page loads hence isAjax becomes true(when ajax called as the page loads) after which it becomes false in else condition thereby going in infinite loop

Comment: @UjjawalSolanki are you executing multiple ajax requests?

Comment: Not it fires the same ajax everytime :)

Comment: @UjjawalSolanki i have no idea what you are saying but the infinite loop should not occur, you have serious problems with your code

Comment: NOTE : Everything is being executed inside the document.ready function..except the ajax which is placed outside of it.

Comment: ******NOTE*****: As soon as the page is loaded, select element updates dynamically hence change event is triggered then and there only which further call the ajax which again updates the select element in dom hence this way it becomes chain request which goes into infinite loop